# International Date "String" Is Subtracting Instead of Remaining in Its Original Format

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When working with Python's Selenium I am attempting to "inject" (my term, b/c of an `execute_script()` call) an international date string in the following format:

```
date_string = `"2015-05-15"`
```

Unfortunately, injecting the `date_string` results in *subtraction* rather than a string (`date_string` equates to `1995` in the present case).  Here is what the relevant code snippet looks like:

```
element = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="ad_start_date"]'))) #locate the element
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ad_start_date').value = {0};".format("2015-05-15")) #"inject" the `date_string` which surprisingly results in `1995`
```

Thus, in other words, I locate the relevant element (a date field) and then attempt to inject `event_date` via JavaScript.  I suspect that the issue is either the `value = {}` line or the `format()` method (since `format()` appears to [treat dashes as subtraction signs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)).

I have tried everything that I can think of to test my `format()` hypothesis, including trying to escape the dashes ("2015-\05-15"), escape the curly brackets (`{{0}}`), wrapping the string in a `str()` method, and constructing `date_string` within the `format()` method itself (e.g. `format("2015" +'-' +"05"+'-'+"15")`).  Also, I've tried to avoid `format()` altogether, relying on `%s` instead.  They all result in `1995` rather than `2015-05-15`.

I am at a bit of a loss, because I don't know how to avoid the issue and that's the format that the site requires.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` function is not the problem, but look at this:

```
>>> "document.getElementById('ad_start_date').value = {0};".format("2015-05-15")
"document.getElementById('ad_start_date').value = 2015-05-15;"
```

The *date* isn't a string any longer, it's an integer!

### Fix

You can solve this by adding extra apostrophes: `date_string = '"2015-05-15"'`
The normal apostrophes make sure it's a string for Python and the double apostrophes make sure it's a string for Javascript.

```
>>> "document.getElementById('ad_start_date').value = {0};".format('"2015-05-15"')
'document.getElementById(\'ad_start_date\').value = "2015-05-15";'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit inconvenient, but you can use the datepicker-api:

```
var d="2015-05-15";
var dateFormated = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(d));
```